# Calculate the delta over a time window of the count of a gauge metric in Prometheus / Grafana

Tags: prometheus

I have a gauge metric, A, that has a label `name`.
I can compute the number of time series using

```
A{name="XYZ"}
```

but I'd like to compute how many new time series were generated in the last 5m, so I tried:

```
delta(count(A{name="XYZ"}[5m]))
```

However it doesn't work due to the error:

```
"1:13: parse error: expected type instant vector in aggregation expression, got range vector"
```

How can I compute the delta of a count() of a gauge metric??

```
delta(count(A{name="XYZ"}[5m]))
```

I expected this to show the delta of the count in a 5-minute sliding window

Comment: Move range selector outside count and make it subquery  compatible: `delta(count(A{name="XYZ"})[5m:])`

Comment: @markalex, what [5m:] vs [5m] means?

Comment: @Anatoly, [5m:] means range of 5m with default resolution. This will use subquery syntax, and thus allows a range selector to be applied to something more complex than mere vector selector. If there is no proper question about that on SO already,  consider asking it: I think it will be useful.